# How do I resolve "Inout expression creates a temporary pointer" issue in Swift 5.2?

Tags: swift5

How do i resolve this issue when i calling `CTParagraphStyleSetting` function in swift 5.2?

```
function myFunction() {
    var alignment: CTTextAlignment = .left
    var settings = CTParagraphStyleSetting(spec: .alignment, 
                                           valueSize: 1, 
                                           value: &alignment)
}

issue:
Inout expression creates a temporary pointer, but argument 'value' should 
be a pointer that outlives the call to 'init(spec:valueSize:value:)'
```

Comment: I do not get that error in a playground, could you add more context and enough code to make it reproducible

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Sorry! It's in a function.

Comment: That is the problem, the moment the function exits your `alignment` variable will disappear so you need to declare outside of the function for example like a property in your struct/class or a static variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In reference to this discussion;

https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-5-2-pointers-and-coretext/34862,

you can write it like this:

```
let alignment: CTTextAlignment = .left
let settings: CTParagraphStyleSetting = withUnsafeBytes(of: alignment) { alignment in
    CTParagraphStyleSetting(
        spec: .alignment, 
        valueSize: 1, 
        value: alignment.baseAddress!
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented the above into THLabel class:

```
   let paragraphStyleSettings: [CTParagraphStyleSetting] = withUnsafeBytes(of: alignment) { alignmentBP in
        withUnsafeBytes(of: lineBreakMode, { lineBreakModeBP in
            withUnsafeBytes(of: lineSpacing, { lineSpacingBP in
                [
                    CTParagraphStyleSetting(spec: .alignment, valueSize: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: alignment), value: alignmentBP.baseAddress!),
                    CTParagraphStyleSetting(spec: .lineBreakMode, valueSize: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: lineBreakMode), value: lineBreakModeBP.baseAddress!),
                    CTParagraphStyleSetting(spec: .lineSpacingAdjustment, valueSize: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: lineSpacing), value: lineSpacingBP.baseAddress!)
                ]
            })
        })
    }
```